# Tag links not working in beautifulhugo blog

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to build a blog using a combination of RStudio/blogdown and using the beautifulhugo theme from halogenica/beautifulhugo. When I create a new website using the stock template from github and the RStudio GUI/serve_site() everything works fine (as far as I can see) except the tags on the main page don't work (when I click them they say my computer isn't connected to the internet). I'd like to find out how to fix this... or learn how to work this properly, before I start changing stuff in the stock setup/building a blog.

This tag issue is repeated on each posts' page and on the dedicated "Tags" page when I click "View all" under each tag.

Am a complete noob here - am likely doing something wrong. I managed to "fix" the "View all" issue using https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo/issues/142, but I'm guessing there is a more general issue with what I'm doing: I need to fix it once centrally, or perhaps perform a similar modification to other parts of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - I found out what was wrong. The above fix corrects one of the issues in terms.html (layouts/_default). In the same folder there was an "error" (which I'll no doubt find out is correct at some point in the future) where there was an extra "/" being put into the tags link. I had to change

```
<a href="{{ $.Site.LanguagePrefix | absURL }}/tags/{{ . | urlize }}/">{{ . }}</a>&nbsp;
```

to

```
<a href="{{ $.Site.LanguagePrefix | absURL }}tags/{{ . | urlize }}/">{{ . }}</a>&nbsp;
```

in both list/single.html in the same folder as above. Note these only differ in the slash before tags.